# Exception specifications as comments at function declarations

Tags: c++, exception, exception-specification

I use C++ exceptions in my code instead of return values to indicate errors, so my code has to be exception safe. Therefore i add an exception specification as comment to my function declarations. For example:

```
// Does x and y. strong-guarantee
void XandY();

// Checks something.
bool CheckSomething() noexcept;
```

Is this good practice?

Further, if i evaluate my code in order to make these specifications, do i have to keep in mind only C++ exceptions or also SEH exceptions like dereferencing nullptr, overflow or dividing by zero exceptions?

Let´s say i use a 3rd-party library which does never throw C++ exceptions, but could throw SEH exceptions. Can my function, which relies on functions of that library, be ever noexcept?

```
void MyFunction() noexcept // <-- Is noexcept viable?
{
    OtherFunction(); // may throw SEH exception
}
```

Comment: `SEH` is Windows term, but `noexcept` is not Visual Studio keyword. Could you specify your compiler and OS?

Comment: You first remark is excellent, it's an essential information about the declaration that cannot be specified by code.

Comment: I use C++ 11 on Windows, but i think there is something similar to SEH on other OS as well.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ exception specification works with C++ exceptions only, and not with Windows exceptions (SEH). In particular, Windows exceptions cannot be caught using C++'s `try-catch` block. Most of the conditions that throw a Windows exception are classified as undefined or implementation-defined behaviors by the standard.

Comment: So i shouldn´t care about them at all?

Comment: It depends on whether you are working on the language level or system level.

Comment: That depends on needs of your application.  If you are calling functions (e.g. in the win32 API or a third party library) that trigger SEH, then you probably need to handle them to ensure your program runs correctly.   That said, prevention is better than cure - it is better to do everything you can to prevent occurences of undefined behaviour than to recover after the fact.    But that is true for use of exceptions too - it is often better to prevent error conditions occurring if at all possible than to recover from an exception after some code has detected the error condition.

Comment: One more question: If the 3rd party function throws SEH of my function call (which is marked noexcept), will std::terminate be called and the program crashes without notice or will windows create a messagebox for me with error message, line numbers etc.?

Comment: @Knowledge In this case, your program crashes without calling `std::terminate`. Usually Windows will display a message box stating the error condition, like `access violation while reading/writing address 0x...`.

Comment: It is possible to add a handler that converts SEH exceptions into C++ exceptions...that's when things get interesting...